# Sharing state between multiple jquery widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing a jQuery application. This application is a combination of multiple jQuery UI Widgets. Basically I want to share an **object** with multiple widgets. The **object** is the ***single primary source of truth*** or you can say the object is the **state** of the widgets. Something like **services** in angularjs.

Each widget will interact with the **object**, to add some data or delete some data to it. Once the interactions is done, the object can be saved in DB or in local Storage.

Here is the simple version of my app structure

```
src
 - app.state.js
 - widgetA.js
 - widgetB.js
```

In app.state.js, i have declared my object in "$".

example :

```
$.ab.state = 
{
  title: "",
  description: "",
  items: [],
  score: 0
}
```

Now this object is been directly accessed in widget's js files. I feel that this shouldn't be like this. There should be an interface for this.

Problem is widgetA can accidentally change the properties in the sate, which it is not supposed to do.

> widgetA is supposed to update the following information in the state
>   object "title", "description".
>
> widgetB is supposed to update the "items" & "score" properties in the
>   state object.

Is there any good design pattern for modeling this type of application ? or Please recommend a best practice to do this.